# Add toolbox to MATLAB manually

Tags: matlab, installation

I am trying to install the Wavelet Toolbox to MATLAB but it seems it won't happen because every time I get this "Your administrator has restricted your download access to this MathWorks product". Is there any way to install it?

Comment: Please describe your environment.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by environment?

Comment: Who has control over the licensing of your Matlab? e.g. your IT support if you are using it in a company or university setting, for example. It is quite possible what you are describing is not an error but a company policy.

Comment: I am using a trial version with my own information, but I live in a university housing and use the university network.